# figure caption leads to error in beamer

Tags: beamer, floats, captions

I get this coompilation error:

```
No file texto-10.nav.
<Valoresparametros.jpg, id=13, 683.55376pt x 356.83313pt>
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmtt.fd)

! You can't use `\unskip' in vertical mode.

\reset@color ...mer@zeropt \else \ifvmode \unskip 

                                                  \fi \ifhmode \unskip \fi \...
l.32   \caption{Valores Sugeridos}

?
```

This is the code I'm using.

Where is the error?

```
\documentclass[draft]{beamer}



\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[figurename=Fig]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[height=1in,width=4.1in]{Valoresparametros}
  \caption{Valores Sugeridos}
  \label{valpar}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a reference for the `figurename` option in the manual of `caption`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}


\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}

% loading both the following packages doesn't make sense
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=1in,width=4.1in]{example-image}
\caption{Valores Sugeridos}\label{valpar}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I removed packages that are useless either because they're already loaded by `beamer` or they do nothing interesting (`float`). Using `\addto\captionsspanish` is the correct way for changing the label.

Note that it makes no sense to load `mathpazo` along with `lmodern`: you'd get math in Palatino and text in Computer Modern Sans.

---

On the other hand, I'm not sure (understatement for I'm certain) that floats make sense in `beamer`. First, as you can clearly see, figure captions are not numbered, so you can only reference them by the slide number, which will distract the audience: “As we saw in the figure four slides before…” is nothing I would like to hear during a talk. *Nobody* will remember the figure number anyway, so it makes little sense to number captions.

Just place the picture and add the explanation as text.

Comment: Hi @egreg It still dont work for me, the error appear once again, I have already add in the code "\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig}}" but the error is appearing again.  The command \mathpazo was for using the \pm command

Comment: @JuanMuñoz `\pm` is defined by the LaTeX kernel and doesn't require any additional package. I get no error from my code. Did you remove `figurename=Fig`?

Comment: @egreg `figurename=Fig` was outsourced to the `newfloat` package but can still be used with `caption` for backward-compatibility reasons. (The `caption` package loads the `newfloat` package automatically when using this option and passes it on to `newfloat`.)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Nice to know, but its usage with babel seems dubious nonetheless

Comment: @egreg If `babel` is loaded the `newfloat` package will use it. (But I agree, for this task neither `caption` not `newfloat` is needed.)